# Win Form Webbrowser Control built in spell check

Tags: c#, vb.net

I am trying to implement a built-in spell checker for a Webbrowser control. I have the spell check functions complete using NHunspell but I have not been able to implement the red underlining (or other function) that would tell the user the word is spelled wrong. I have attempted many different routes to obtain this functionality. I have even tried the webkit.net and Gecko Webbrowsers, still nothing.

All I want to do is highlight or underline a word within a text field of a Webbrowser control.

Answer (score 0):

You'd need to extract the text from the DOM and normalize text-nodes (so `"he<span>ll</span>o"` becomes `"hello"`) and then pass that into your spellchecker. You would then need to surround the incorrect text fragments with a `<span>` element (in a correct fashion, so you can't surround a `<div>` with a span for example, you'd need to devise an algorithm that takes this into account).

With CSS2 your only options are for simple solid, dashed or dotted red underlines or using a wavy-underline defined as a repeating background image aligned to the bottom edge. I believe CSS3 makes it easier.